# Loader element always in centered position

Tags: jquery, positioning

I have a very simple loader like this one

```
<i class="icon-refresh icon-spin"></i> //font awesome
```

and I use it on all ajax requests. The response of the ajax request is inserted with `.html()` into different dom elements defined by the request itself, it can by the smallest div as the whole page.

My problem is that I would like to position the loader always in the middle of the target element, center width and middle height.

Any idea?

Comment: "Any idea?" No, not with the small snippet of code you've posted.

Comment: container has to be `position: relative` and spinner `position: absolute`, then you set it's `left` property to 50% - (spinner width)/2 and it's `top` property to 50% - (spinner height)/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a css question:

```
.containerForAjaxContent { position: relative; }
.icon-refresh.icon-spin { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; }
```

A note about absolute positioning:

> So, let’s summarize this in a set of easy steps—to find the containing
>   block for an element with position:absolute , this is what you need to
>   do:
>
> Look at the parent element of the absolutely positioned element—does
>   that element’s position property have one of the values relative,
>   absolute or fixed?
>
> If so, you’ve found the containing block.
>
> If not, move to the parent’s parent element and repeat from step 1
>   until you find the containing block or run out of ancestors.
>
> If you’ve reached the html element without finding a positioned
>   ancestor, then the containing block is the html element.

source: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Containing_blocks

Comment: an element with position:absolute will position itself relative to the closest ancestor with its position set to 'relative', 'fixed' or 'absolute', see my edit above